# Streaming video, cloud servers, and videojs

Tags: streaming, cloud, html5-video, codec, video.js

I'm interested in setting up a streaming video server (perhaps on a cloudfront server) with videojs. I understand that flash video can be streamed, however, is it possible to stream video using videojs and a different codec? (like h246). I tried looking through the videojs documentation and forums but did not find any additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Video.js has limited support for RTMP streaming in Flash, but hopefully more in the next few months.

HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) is the most supported streaming format for HTML5 (iOS, Safari, latest Android). Video.js can support that on the devices that support HLS natively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to transcode the h264 file on the fly to get the effect you want. Subsonic is a program which will read your file structure, display your videos and music in a webui, transcode the audio/video and stream it--but it uses jwplayer, not videojs.

However, it is opensource, so if you want to try to modify that, I'm sure it would be possible.